# how to allocate memory for a type when we don't know the size of it?

Tags: c++, arrays, io

just a simple question.
I want to receive some integers and put it into an array but I don't know the size of it as it's given by user
The input is expected to be like: 1 2 3 4 5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *contain;
    int y;
    int i=0;
    char c;

    while(true)
    {
        cin>>contain[i];
        i++;
        c=getchar();
        if(c=='\n')
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user inputs a size you can allocate that number. Just make it easy and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Read them into a container that grows as you add items. e.g. std::vector. That way you don't need to know beforehand how many you will read.

Comment: This is supposed to be a data structure question, so I can not allocate extra spaces.

Comment: There's no such thing as size given by user.

Comment: I'm kind of new to vector but I know you should give it the size

Comment: vector doesnt need the size. It's just that if you can give it the size it will be more efficient as it wont need to reallocate as often.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll do it

Comment: Std::vector is great but hides stuff I think is good to know.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). This way you needn't know the size beforehand.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Input
    vector<int> data(istream_iterator<int>(cin), {});

    // Output
    for (auto i : data)
        cout << i << endl;

    // Output 2: suggested by alfC
    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

See it working at <kbd>[Ideone](https://www.ideone.com/d5Vmll)</kbd>

Comment: That's a better answer, Nzim accept that one instead.

Comment: Such a cool answer should end with `std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));` instead of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your helping but I gotta see what it is as I'm new to vector and istream_iterator

Comment: @Nznin read http://en.cppreference.com

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Demonstrative example to get you started, that will read numbers and store them into a vecotr, until 0 is read (it will stored in the vector too):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  int myint;

  std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to end):\n";

  do {
    std::cin >> myint;
    myvector.push_back (myint);
  } while (myint);

  std::cout << "myvector stores " << int(myvector.size()) << " numbers.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter some integers (enter 0 to end):
1 2 3 4 5 0
myvector stores 6 numbers.
```

---

In the C-like code you have, you would need to use `realloc()` for example, and increase the size by 1, every time a new number arrived (very inefficient).

Comment: Resize operations for arrays are often done incrementally, not only 1 by 1, to avoid doing too much resize. #randomTip

Comment: @alseether that's why I said that this would be very inefficient. In practise, you would double the size every time you would need to re-allocate.

Comment: so you mean it's like amortized allocation

Comment: @Nznin you mean in the vector? The vector is  a C++ container that handles the size of the container under the hood (automatically).

Comment: how can I end it when there is a \n?

Comment: Check the other answer @Nznin, I only gave a demonstrative example to get you started.